# Detailed description of parse errors in PHP

Tags: php, macos

I've never had to edit my own php.ini file before. I'm setting up my mac at home to work like my server at work does. One problem is that parse errors in PHP don't give me any useful information. For example,

```
echo 'A'
echo 'B';
```

At work this gives me:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';' in
>   /path/index.php on line 2

At home, I get:

> Parse error: parse error in /path/index.php on
>   line 7

How can I change this? Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Maybe different versions of PHP?

Comment: Are you using the same server at both end like (`Apache,Nginx`)?

Comment: May I point out that your filenames are different? The first thing I'd like to ask, is are you absolutely positively 100% sure you're running the same file, with the same exact content?

Comment: Using Apache for both. Yes they are different versions but the one at home is newer, is this something that was deprecated in newer versions? As for the filenames, I just wrote the path out wrong, it's the same file.

Comment: What are the php versions in each case ?
You can customize your error message with the error_handler function, see http://php.net/manual/fr/function.set-error-handler.php .

Comment: Always install the latest stable PHP version to have better error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your php.ini, make sure you have set

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = on
```

This should show you all errors. Also, if you're running a PHP version lower than 5.4, make sure to include E_STRICT (see http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

Easiest would probably be to get a copy of the php.ini at your work and compare it to the one on your computer to see what the differences are.